# Clean way of sharing data between BLoCs

Tags: dart, flutter

Imagine the following pseudo blocs:

```
class BlocA {
  BlocA() {
     //some initialization
   }
   Stream a;
   Stream b;
   Stream c;
   }


class BlocB {
  BlocB() {
    //some initialization
  }
  Stream d; //dependant on a piece of data that resides in BlocA
}
```

What is the cleanest way of passing information from one bloc to another, how to handle this dependency?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can inject as parameter to your BlocB the BlocA.

```
class BlocA {
  Stream a;
}

class BlocB {
  final BlocA _a;

  BlocB(this._a);
}
```

Alternatively, you can pass only the stream you need instead of the whole block. But do that only if the number of streams is very limited.

You can then freely map/pipe streams from A to expose a different one into B.

```
class BlocB {
  Stream b;

  BlocB(BlocA blocA) {
    b = blocA.a.map((a) => 42).asBroadcastStream();
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree with @Remi.. in case 2, it's better to send the stream to constructor like `BlocB(this.b)`

Comment: @Remi is have you tried this with scoped blocs, I have tried it with a global bloc (one that wraps the entire application). However when i try to get a reference to a scoped bloc after navigating, it just gives me null since the inherited widget that provides the bloc is no longer accessible to the new route I have navigated to

Comment: The problem is that your global bloc depends on a scoped bloc when it shouldn't. Either your global bloc should be scoped too, or your scoped bloc should be global. You may want to move some streams around too

Comment: No what I meant is if one scoped bloc is dependent on another scoped bloc, for example a screen that user chooses some products from has it is own bloc, and then he can navigate to the cart page where he can checkout or edit his choices also has it is own bloc as well, now I need to share data from ChooseProductsBloc to CartBloc, is this possible ?

Comment: You can make a global bloc that contains the data shared by both these blocs. And make both scoped blocs depends on the global one

Comment: You mean the bloc that wraps the entire application? this will make the global bloc huge, I just want a single bloc related to a single screen to share data with another bloc related to another screen. So this is impossible using scoped blocs ?

Comment: Like with any shared data between routes, you need it to be global.

Comment: @RémiRousselet If I am working with flutter_bloc library and I have same scenario where `Bloc B` depends on `Bloc A`, so I should inject `Bloc A` into `Bloc B` and then it will be ok (i.e. good practice) to fire events of `Bloc A` from inside `Bloc B`? (note: `Bloc A` lives above `Bloc B`)